# Crash in Spark-SQL for windowed function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 2.3.2 and Spark-SQL, the following query 'b' fails:

```
import spark.implicits._

val dataset = Seq((30, 2.0), (20, 3.0), (19, 20.0)).toDF("age", "size")

import functions._
val a0 = dataset.withColumn("rank", rank() over Window.partitionBy('age).orderBy('size))
val a1 = a0.agg(avg('rank))
//a1.show()
//OK

//same thing but in one expression, crashes:
val b = dataset.agg(functions.avg(functions.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('age).orderBy('size))))
```

AFAIK this is pretty weird but this is a legit SQL query:

- I'm defining a column that is the result of a windowing function
- then taking the average

Doing it by using an intermediary column works, but doing it in a single expression makes catalyst crash with a stack overflow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.find(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.find(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$find$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:109)
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.find(TreeNode.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$$hasWindowFunction(Analyzer.scala:1757)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$$anonfun$71.apply(Analyzer.scala:1781)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$$anonfun$71.apply(Analyzer.scala:1781)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$partition$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:314)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$partition$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:314)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.partition(TraversableLike.scala:314)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.partition(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$$extract(Analyzer.scala:1781)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$$anonfun$apply$28.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1950)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ExtractWindowExpressions$$anonfun$apply$28.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1925)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272) [...]
```

Is this a known issue?
I'm not 100% sure my query is correct but it should at least not crash catalyst, as it's crashing even before I'm able to evaluate my query

Comment: erg, seems it is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21896

Answer (score 0):

avg() takes in column name as argument, but rank() is passing the actual column data, so it couldn't find the column name.

It works same as:

```
dataset.select( rank().over(Window.partitionBy("age").orderBy("size")).as("rank_XX") 
     ).
     agg(avg("rank_XX")).show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+                                                                  
|avg(rank_XX)|
+------------+
|         1.0|
+------------+
```